# How to transmit data from Nodejs program to Java program?

Tags: java, node.js, stream, pipe

Inside the Java class is the following:

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("node /home/master/code/nodejs/searchLi.js");
process.waitFor();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
String line = null;
while ( (line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    builder.append(line);
    builder.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
}
String result = builder.toString();
System.out.println(result);
```

Inside the nodejs searchLi is the following:

```
const Stream = require('stream');
const readableStream = new Stream.Readable();
readableStream.push('ping!');
readableStream.push('pong!');
console.log("success");
return "success";
```

As you can see I tried to implement streams but failed. How to transmit a String from the nodejs file to the Java file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Java code is fine, but your node.js code isn't using streams properly. Either just stop using a stream of your own and just use `process.stdout.write` instead, or fix your streams to point there, like this:

```js
const Stream = require('stream');
const readableStream = new Stream.Readable();
readableStream.push('ping!');
readableStream.push('pong!');
readableStream.push(null);
readableStream.pipe(process.stdout);
console.log("success");
return "success";
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can setup a http server, although for something this small (a string) I suggest using the `fs` npm library to create a file and have the java program read from it.

I'm not experienced in java but I assume that there is a file reading library.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I was just wondering if it was possible to use the return value directly as you would with 2 files of the same language? Are the streams a viable option in your opinion?

Comment: Spawning an HTTP server to just to communicate between a parent and child process is quite frankly one of the most overcomplicated solutions I've ever heard.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica  I'm not proficient in this kind of stuff, and I didn't suggest that as the solution.

Comment: @propre_poli streams are definetely what you should use, the other answer gives you a good solution. I looked through streams and it seems like it uses my file solution's flow but optimizes it.